# Can't find System.Media in Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I am currently working on a project for a music player in C# that requires the use of System.Media. I have tried adding it in my assemblies, but System.Media is no where to be found.

```
using System;
using System.Media; //gives an error and suggests to add a reference/assembly

namespace ConsoleMusic
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Cream Crossroads.mp3";
            player.Play();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture of available assemblies]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code and you don't need another reference. [`System.Media.SoundPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of `System.dll`. Which version of .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: @DavidG I am currently targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Then this should work fine.

Comment: This should work fine.  What problem are you having?

Comment: @Amy "The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Can you confirm that you have an assembly reference to `System.dll`?  If it is present, then I have no idea why you would get that error.

Comment: I just pasted your code into LinqPad and it works fine.

Comment: Looks like it's .Net Core.

Comment: @Jimi That's why I asked what version of .NET was being used above, it's not.

Comment: @DavidG  Console application without `System.Media`? That's what comes to mind.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, but OP [says otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296895/cant-find-system-media-in-assemblies?noredirect=1#comment87610811_50296895)

Comment: It is possible that the OP was mistaken when he said he's targeting .Net Framework 4.6.1.  That's the easiest explanation, here, though I admit that would conflict with the information presented in the screenshot.